# Make Gulp task synchronous without creating a bunch of other tasks

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, file-io, gulp

So I am writing up my `gulpfile.js` and I have come to a point where I need to avoid JavaScript's asynchronous behavior. In short, this is for file-system read/write.

The problem is that all the solutions I have found online thus far create several sub-tasks; which is something I want to avoid so that I don't have to write any confusing documentation about what tasks should and shouldn't be used in the command line, and what order they need to be run in, etc.

**My Question:** How can I make the below script run each part synchronously, without creating sub-tasks?

```
gulp.task('rebuild', function(){
    // Remove old build
    gulp.src('build/', {read: false}).
        pipe(rimraf());

    // Copy all of the non generated files
    gulp.src('src/**/*').
        pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));

    // Parse SASS/LESS and minify JS
    build_styles();
    build_scripts();
});
```

Comment: Two notes for you to consider: Breaking things down into smaller tasks can be very helpful e.g. if you need to build only styles or only scripts. You shouldn't have to document ordering of tasks, because gulp will determine the order using task dependencies.

Comment: It would be one thing if I only needed to break into 2-3 sub-tasks, but in this case, I would need to break down each task into 5 or more sub-tasks. (the above example was shortened)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if all else fail, you can always fall back to the callback hell:

```
gulp.task('rebuild', function(){
    // Remove old build
    gulp.src('build/', {read: false}).
        pipe(rimraf())
        .on('end', function () {
            // Copy all of the non generated files
            gulp.src('src/**/*').
                pipe(gulp.dest('build/'))
                .on('end', function () {
                    // Parse SASS/LESS and minify JS
                    build_styles();
                    build_scripts();
                });
        });
});
```

Comment: I ended up using sub-tasks with a `:` as a separator. (e.g. `build:minify`) But this would work well too.

Comment: Yeah I dont recommend anyone doing this. Gulp 4 will make task parallelism a bit clearer